# responsive mdl-cards get distributed strange when having min-width

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Screenshot: [image: mdl-cards with min-width]

PHP/HTML

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title'); ?>

    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h3 class="mdl-card__title-text">

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title'); ?>

        </h3>

    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text product-card-supporting-text">

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title'); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect product-card-button-left">
            Get a Quote
        </a>
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect product-card-button-right">
            Add to Cart
        </a>
    </div>
</a>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'); ?>
```

CSS

```
.mx-product-card {
  width: 270px;
  min-width: 270px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

without the min-width it works fine, and the mdl-cards get distributed correctly.
But then the mdl-cards get very slim and look strange on certain devices.

Screenshot: [image: mdl-cards without min-width]

What can I do to make it work properly?
I want the mdl-cards to distribute so that all lines are always filled equally and the mdl-cards don't get shrinked and squeezed.

Comment: Unless you're having a problem with the PHP->HTML or Sass->CSS compilation, only provide the compiled HTML/CSS.

Comment: Maybe create a plunkr (or similar) of your base code for people to review and edit.

Comment: http://codepen.io/fabianhenzler/pen/gajXXp
Does this help?

Comment: if you narrow the screen down from the side you can see the effect